# AS3 - Class postfix

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, postfix-notation

Is it possible to create a class that uses a postfix, like the Vector class

```
var vect:Vector.<MyClass> = new Vector.<MyClass>();
```

I know this isn't really a constructive question, but it's all I have. And Google didn't reveal anything useful. I just thought this would be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [`generics`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) and, no, the current actionscript specification does not permit custom defined generic classes